# My first calendar loops the days in one month over 30 times

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, calendar

I'm trying to create a own calendar to my gallery but I can't get it to work as I want it to work. I have added a SQL query so I can get when my photos are taken and make the date to be linked. To link correct day for every photo is not any problem here. It's how it's looping the days in every month.

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';

$months = Array(1 => 'Januari',
                2 => 'Februari',
                3 => 'Mars',
                4 => 'April',
                5 => 'Maj',
                6 => 'Juni',
                7 => 'Juli',
                8 => 'Augusti',
                9 => 'September',
                10 => 'Oktober',
                11 => 'November',
                12 => 'December');

foreach($months AS $month_n => $month) {

    # DATABAS: photos (hämta)
    $get_photosdate = "SELECT photo_exif_taken FROM photos";


    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td align="right" class="calendar-month" width="50">';
            echo '<a href="'.url('sortby/date/2012/'.($month_n < 10 ? '0'.$month_n : $month_n)).'" title="Sortera fotografierna efter den här månaden">';
                echo '<b>'.$month.'</b>';
            echo '</a>';
        echo '</td>';

        echo '<td align="left" class="calendar-day">';
            foreach($sql->query($get_photosdate) AS $date) {
                for($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++) {
                    if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date['photo_exif_taken'])) == '2012-'.$month_n.'-'.$i) {
                        echo '<a href="'.url('sortby/date/2012/'.($month_n < 10 ? '0'.$month_n : $month_n).'/'.($i < 10 ? '0'.$i : $i)).'" class="calendar-link" title="Sortera fotografierna efter den här dagen">';
                            echo $i < 10 ? '<span style="color: #a16e74;">0</span>'.$i : $i;
                        echo '</a>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<span style="padding: 2px 3px;">';
                            echo $i < 10 ? '<span style="color: #a2a1a1;">0</span>'.$i : $i;
                        echo '</span>';
                    }

                    if($i == 11 OR $i == 22) {
                        echo '<br>';
                    }
                }
            }
        echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
```

It should print the days like this: `01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16` and so on. But it prints `01 02 03 04 05 06 ... 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 01 02 03 04 05 06` and so on like 50 times or so, until it change the month.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outermost foreach loops through months, the second one loops through the results of your queries, and the innermost for loops from 1 to 31.

So if your query gives e.g. 5 results, you loop

12 (months) * 5 (count of results) * 31 times.

You should probably restructure the way you work through dates by thinking through what you want, step by step. E.g: If you want to show images on a calender, you could build the calender as a multidimensional array and then place the images on the correct indexes.

Edit: If you want to do a real calender, you should also consider using php builtin functionality, so you get the correct number of days in a month. mktime ( http://php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php ) or the php DateTime ( http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php ) object would probably be helpful to you.

Comment: That's very true. I will reconstruct the loops and try again :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating the day listing for each element of the photo array. I expect you have 50 or so photos in the database, and they are causing the extra looping.

Rework the query loop so that it does not work based on the number of photos.